# Can I delete downloaded JNLP file (Java web start/JWS) from Java application?

Tags: java, google-chrome, jnlp, java-web-start

Google Chrome does not launch JNLP file automatically, so I recommend for our users [this solution](http://www.windowsreference.com/google-chrome/google-chrome-doesnt-launch-jnlp-files-automatically/). It works but the downloaded JNLP file remains in download folder. Deleting them manually is troublesome.

I want to add a function to our Java application:

1. Google Chrome downloads a JNLP file and open it.
2. The JNLP file starts our Java application.
3. The Java application deletes the JNLP file (<= I want this function!)

Can I get the file path of the downloaded JNLP file which started the Java application?
Of cause, our Java application jar is signed and can access local resources.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing in the Java WebStart paper that describes such a mechanism, hence you are in "vendor-specific" territory, and I do not think that there is an API letting your application know where the JNLP file is.

You can, however, provide a replacement for javaws which invoke the original javaws with -wait and delete the JNLP file afterwards.  This must be installed by the user.

Comment: Thanks. I understand such API may be not available.
Your solution(replacement javaws) is very interesting. I will try it in the future release.

Comment: What do you mean by replacement for javaws? how can i delete downloaded jnlp file after it getting launched? can you please elaborate launching of javaws with -wait and delete ?

Comment: Why do you Want this?