# Opening JNLP in Chrome - prevent file download dialog?

Tags: java, jnlp, java-web-start

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I delete downloaded JNLP file (Java web start/JWS) from Java application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9348449/can-i-delete-downloaded-jnlp-file-java-web-start-jws-from-java-application)
>   [Launch webstart without downloading…?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11679373/launch-webstart-without-downloading)

I created a JWS program that starts by clicking an HTML link that takes you to the JNLP file. However, what Chrome browser does, it presents a file download dialog asking if you want to "keep" or "discard" the file. A lot of users oversee that dialog and never click on "keep".

But in some websites I see that that dialog is not present and the JWS is automatically launched. How can I do the same in my case?

Example of direct launch:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html

Comment: *"Example of direct launch:"* Ughh.  Did it not occur to you to link to your JNLP that breaks, ***as well as*** one that works?  It is probably down to mime-type, and I might have checked that in the time it took to type this comment.

Comment: Sorry, but the other is on closed environment. Mime-type is set and shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 6):

That page uses the java deployment toolkit http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html#deplToolkit.

It is a javascript that does some other things for you as well, as ensuring an installed jre on the client machine and so on.

you can find it here: http://java.com/js/deployJava.js or a human readable version here: http://www.java.com/js/deployJava.txt

basicaly you use it like this:

```
<script src="http://www.java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>
<script>
    var url = "http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/javawebstart apps/notepad.jnlp";
    deployJava.createWebStartLaunchButton(url, '1.6.0');
</script>
```